# Where can I find simulation software for electricity and magnets?

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations, simulations, software

Is there easily-available* software to simulate coils, solenoids, and other magnetic and electromagnetic devices?

I'd like to play around with some design ideas, such as Halbach arrays, but physics simulators like SketchyPhysics don't seem to have the laws of electromagnetism implemented.

(*"Easily-available" means "not cost prohibitive.")

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for software and not about physics.

Answer (score 13):

Try Finite Element Magnetics (Link [FEMM](http://www.femm.info/wiki/HomePage))

[image]

Did I mention is free to download and use. Go figure !

Answer (score 9):

There are a number of commercial packages you can use for such purposes.

Comsol multiphysics simulation software is a general purpose physics modelling software package that I belive can deal with electromagnitism. The link to their website is http://www.uk.comsol.com.

Ansys is another commercial vendor that provides a electromagnetic physics module. There website is http://www.ansys.com.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

There are the [EMS](http://www.emworks.com/product/preview/1/EMS), an add-in to Solidowrks, so you can simulate in 3D:  (payed).

Others:

- [Amperes](http://www.integratedsoft.com/Products/Amperes)
- [Quickfield](http://www.quickfield.com/glossary/electromagnetic_simulation.htm)
- [MagNet](http://www.infolytica.com/en/products/magnet)

Open source:

- [MaxFEM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/maxfem/)

Comment: Could you comment on the pros/cons of any of these software?

Comment: MaxFEM seems to have moved and I'm unable to locate a copy would you know if there is a repository for it somewhere ?

Answer (score 0):

You can draw virtual magnets and view theirr magnetic fields using [www.pic2mag.com](http://www.pic2mag.com)

It is a free download.

[image: Pic2Mag Version v1.01 Released]