# Good Magnetic Simulation Software?

Tags: electromagnetism, simulations, software

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find simulation software for electricity and magnets?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14179/where-can-i-find-simulation-software-for-electricity-and-magnets)

I am looking for a good, FREE software that allows me to play with magnets, coils, generators, the whole works. It is (HOPEFULLY!) professional and easy to use.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14179/2451