# finite version of perfect electric dipole

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, dipole, dipole-moment

Is there a finite object whose charge distribution is a perfect dipole (only has a dipole moment) yet doesn't involve any infinities or discontinuities in the fields?  And if there happens to be a fairly  "standard" object in textbooks or literature, that would be even better.

One example of a perfect dipole is a sphere of material with a uniform polarization. Outside of the sphere, in a multipole expansion the potential only has a dipole moment, so this configuration looks like a perfect dipole externally.

Another example of a perfect dipole is a pair of opposite charges ($\pm q$) in the limit that the distance between them ($d$) goes to zero but their charge increases such that $p = qd$ remains constant.

Neither of these objects is easy to analyze rigorously. The uniformly polarized sphere at least doesn't involve a limit procedure with charges going to infinity, but it does have discontinuities in the electric field at the surface (although the potential is still continuous; I was initially incorrect on that).

---

In case any such object is very complicated, and so the motivation behind the question would help frame an answer, I was thinking about this after reading [Electromagnetic field energy "paradox"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/361097/electromagnetic-field-energy-paradox) and wondering if the answer is hidden in the discontinuities of the field.

Comment: Related: [Is there a finite-sized charge distribution whose electric field is *exactly* that of a point dipole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/336512/is-there-a-finite-sized-charge-distribution-whose-electric-field-is-exactly-th). Note that OP's request to keep the electric field continuous makes them different enough to keep this one open.

Comment: Does it need to be finite, or are exponential tails in the charge distribution OK?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Actually, expanding on the central statement of that other answer I think gives an answer to this too. Choose $\rho(\mathbf{r}) = f(r)g(\theta,\phi)$ where $g$ is the spherical harmonic we want. If $\rho$ is finite, the electric field should be continuous (or at least I believe so).

Comment: Yeah, that is correct. Maybe you can answer your own question, then?