Good, easy program for plotting 3D vector fields and/or stream lines
I need to plot some electric and magnetic fields in 3D. Can anyone recommend a good program - something easy where I can just insert the vector field components?
Edit: I am plotting the E and B fields of a circularly polarized (finite) wave packet. I can provide the x, y, and z components of the vector field - I want to plot (draw) either a vector field with arrow length corresponding to field magnitude, or flow lines (field lines).
The other posts referenced do not provide assistance with this. This is not a duplicate question.

How about Software Recommendation SE instead?

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14179/2451 and links therein.

Like this? https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/plot3d/sage/plot/plot3d/plot_field3d.html https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJw9xjEKwCAMAMDdV2QzKSkUOvctUtSCIFVURPP6DgVvusGTBS7od0E9YIJoUjmmZrq3LRXzBB%5Fd6RDHZlNFIYZ9rtbwohCxAsDBB%2DdADDjX5B%2DpD5qKHgM=&lang=sage

Software recommendations aren't really on topic here.

You can use matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 10)
y = np.linspace(-5, 5, 10)
z = np.linspace(-5, 5, 10)
X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(x, y, z)

U = X
V = Y
W = Z

ax.quiver(X, Y, Z, U, V, W, length=0.5, normalize=True)

ax.set_xlabel('X-axis')
ax.set_ylabel('Y-axis')
ax.set_zlabel('Z-axis')

plt.show()


Mathematica is an excellent software to full fill your needs. The manual of Mathematica will satisfy all your curiosity regarding plotting.
